# Is there a way to execute strings in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I've created an array that holds all possible html tag which when run would navigate to the target string or nothing.

```
group = ['div','span','a','link','dl','dt','dd','b','p','meta','']
comb = []

for g1 in group:
    if g1 != '':
        for g2 in group:
            if g2 != '':
                for g3 in group:
                    if g3 != '':
                        res = "tag."+g1+"."+g2+"."+g3+".string"
                        comb.append(res)
                    else:
                        res = "tag."+g1+"."+g2+".string"
                        comb.append(res)
            else:
                res = "tag."+g1+".string"
                comb.append(res)
```

I want to run each entry in the array to see what it returns from a given website.

```
def get_web_price(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}

    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
    tag = soup.find(class_=re.compile("price"))

    for c in comb:
        exec(c, globals())
```

Is there a way to run string in a list as code like what `exec()` does?
I'm using BeautifulSoup, Requests, Googlesearch and Re on Python 3

Comment: I don't understand what you are actually trying to do. Elaborate your problem and provide example(s) if applicable.

Comment: Maybe you can explain this sentence more clearly, and everyone will understand it."I want to run each entry in the array to see what it returns from a given website."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `exec()` nor `eval()` for dynamic attribute access, use `getattr()`, or in case of `BeautifulSoup` the method `find()` to get the first child matching given criteria:

```
from itertools import chain, product

group = ['div','span','a','link','dl','dt','dd','b','p','meta']
# Produce a list of tuples of element names
comb = list(chain(*[product(*[group] * n) for n in range(1, 4)]))

def get_web_price(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}

    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
    tag = soup.find(class_=re.compile("price"))

    for c in comb:
        t = tag
        for a in c:
            t = t.find(a)
            if not t:
                break

        if not t:
            continue

        # Do something with t.string
        t.string
```

You could also use `select()` with a limit for the same effect, I think:

```
def get_web_price(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}

    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
    tag = soup.find(class_=re.compile("price"))

    for c in comb:
        selector = ' '.join(c)
        r = tag.select(selector, limit=1)
        if r:
            r = r[0]

        else:
            continue

        r.string
```

As to if scraping Google search results is a good idea or not, I take no sides.